# R - normalization rows

Tags: r, rows

How can I get each row of a table divided by the sum of each one but in an easier way than what I've done (without the loop)?:

```
tab<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(3,6,7,2))
tab$tot<-rowSums(tab)

ult<-ncol(tab)

for (i in 1:nrow(tab)) 
{for (j in 1:(ult-1))
{
  tab[i, (ult+j)]<- tab[i,j]/tab[i,ult]
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

`/` is vectorized so simply :

```
tab/tab$tot
```

You can of course remove the last column.

```
tab[,-ncol(tab)]/tab$tot
```